# finding the domain of a probability density function calculus

Tags: calculus

The function f(x)=-32x+8 over the interval [0,b].   What is B?
I do not understand this question in my mathbook

Answer (score 0):

If $-32x+8$ with support $[0,\,b]$ is a pdf, $$1=\int_0^b (-32x+8)dx=-16b^2+8b.$$But $16b^2-8b+1=0$ has a single repeated root, $b=\frac{1}{4}$. Note that if $b$ were any greater the pdf would become negative in places, which is impossible.